# Dropdown in list data

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

This is my code:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Html::dropDownList('status', ['10' => 'Active', '20' => 'Deactive']);
    },
],
```

I just want dropdown in status column. If record is active or deactive it will be selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `'format' => 'raw'` for the column options and your definition for the `dropDownList()` is wrong you need to have the selection string as the second parameter and the dropdown options as the third parameter. Change your code to below:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'format' => 'raw',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        return Html::dropDownList('status', $model->status, ['10' => 'Active', '20' => 'Deactive']);
    },
],
```

#### EDIT

You didnt had in the initial requirements that you waned to update the status too when the drop down is changed. You can bind ajax call to the drop-down.

Add the following javascript on top of your view where you are initializing the `GridView`.

***NOTE: Change the `url:'controller/update-status?id'+id` in the ajax call to the relative controller where you want to update the status for the row, but dont remove the `id`***

```
$js = <<<JS
        $(document).on('ready pjax:success',function(){
            $(".switch-status").on('change',function(){
                var data={};
                data[$(this).attr("name")]=$(this).val();
                var id=$(this).closest("tr").data('key');
                $.ajax({
                    method:'post',
                    url:'/controller/update-status?id='+id,
                    data:data,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(!data.success){
                            alert(data.message);
                        }else{
                            alert("Status updated.");
                        }
                    },
                    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js, yii\web\View::POS_END);
```

Then inside your GridView column for `status` change the dropdown to the following

```
return Html::dropDownList(Html::getInputName($model, 'active'), $model->active, [10 => 'Active', 20 => 'Deactive'], ['class' => 'switch-status']);
```

And the go to your controller and add the action code for updating the status

Note: Change the `Model` in the first line `$model = Model::findOne($id);` name with the respective model you are using.

```
public function actionUpdateStatus($id) {
    $model = Affiliate::findOne($id);
    $app = Yii::$app;
    $request = $app->request;

    if($request->IsAjax && $request->isPost) {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        if($model->load($request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return ['success' => true];
        } else {
            return [
                'success' => false,
                'message' => implode('<br />', ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->errors, '0'))
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`content`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-column#$content-detail) property to render HTML elements. For example:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'status',
    'content' => function ($model) {
       return Html::dropDownList('status', $model->status, ['10' => 'Active', '20' => 'Deactive']);
    },
],
```

Comment: How to do which one is selected and also update this value ie onchange

Comment: You should use ajax for sending the change request to your backend, which must update the status of your model